# Two Forms in jquery onclick of submit Loading symbol has to change

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am working jquery form. Where I have two forms in a page and when I submit the form one form should say **please wait** for the button clicked.

And other form display loading symbol instead of please wait.
Please find my code in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/karthic2914/9pn2o6fy/24/)

Here is my reference code

```
$("form").submit(function() {
  if ($("email").validate().checkForm()) {
   $(this).find('input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', true);
   $(this).find('input[type=submit]').prop('value', 'Please wait...');
 } else if ($("sample_data").validate().checkForm()) {
   $(this).find('input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', true);
   $(this).find('input[type=submit]').prop();
   //How to add gif image here
 }
 });
```

Here is the HTML code

```
    <form name="email" action="#" method="post">
  <label for="email">Your Email</label>
  <input name="Email" id="email" type="email">
  <input type="button" value="submit">
</form><br /><br />
<h2>
  Testing Form
</h2>
<form name="sample_data">
  <label for="fname">First Name</label>
  <input name="fname" id="fname_id" type="text"><br />
  <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
  <input name="lname" id="lname_id" type="text">
    <input type="button" value="submit">
</form>
<div class="loadingio-spinner-spinner-cm0pdtzvpde">
  <div class="ldio-rfcqdr7w4x">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please let me know What I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Wheres the html? What is `$("email")`. Is this an Id (`#`) or Class (`.`)?

Comment: @Greg thanks for the reply email is the form name available in jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- To call `$("form").submit()`, you will need to change your input button to submit. That is `<input type="submit" value="submit">`
- To prevent the form from being submitted to the server you will need to pass in `e`, which is the event and call `e.preventDefault();`. This will allow the JQuery code to continue to run.
- `("email").validate().checkForm()` - I wasn't too sure what you intentions were. If you want to call the checkForm method on the email form then try `$("form[name='email'").validate().checkForm()`. Alternatively you could add an ID or Class to the form.

Here is a demo https://jsfiddle.net/xptycbu7/

Comment: thanks for the reply 

there is a small correct is needed for the second form instead of please wait I need to show gif image that is css class which have i know to show that

Comment: It's hard to work out what you're trying to achieve. However this should point you in the right direction https://jsfiddle.net/yprz8esu/

Comment: Thanks @Greg the issue is fixed